# Secondary mailbox reminders not popping up Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

An Outlook 2007 user has her personal exchange mailbox, plus a secondary mailbox added as an additional mailbox in primary Exchange account properties.

In her personal emails, if she right-clicks on an email > Follow up > Set Reminder the reminder pops up at the scheduled time, but if she does the same thing on email in her secondary mailbox, they don't pop up for the Payroll Mailbox.

Additionally, there is no hidden reminders like this:

[image]

Comment: Please specify how both the mailboxes are set up - Exchange/ MAPI, IMAP, Pop. If possible specifics of the Email servers if you have / can find some of that information. Are the calendars being synced? 
Please post a screenshot of the outlook "folders" view if possible.

Comment: How exactly this additional mailbox is configured? As additional mailbox in primary Exchange account properties or as a separate Exchange account?

Comment: It's as an additional mailbox in primary Exchange account properties @thims.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to get reminders from the additional Exchange mailbox, you need to add it as a secondary Exchange account. So, remove it from additional mailboxes first and then add the secondary Exchange account in Outlook Accounts.

Comment: Thanks thims. Does that mean she will have to open each mailbox one at a time, and not view both at the same time?

Comment: No, from the user's point of view, everything will look just the same as now.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot add a 2nd Exchange account in Outlook 2007. Only 1 Exchange account is allowed per Outlook profile. I tried creating a secondary Outlook profile, but got stuck when working out the connection parameters to connect only to the shared mailbox.